# Condition for two line to be coplanar

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

I want to know what is the condition for two lines to be coplanar . I searched it on internet.

I found that for coplanar the scalar product should be zero  .

---

But I could not understand why it should be zero . And what are the three vectors whose scalar product is zero

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071456/coplanar-lines-in-3d-plane/2071461#2071461

Comment: @Rohan in that you have not mentioned about saclar product

Comment: In general we check for coplanarity like that.

Comment: @Rohan can you post an answer in detail explanation.

Comment: 3 vectors or 2 vectors?

Comment: @Ramanujan I am talking of lines

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The lines are parallel or intersect  if not they are not coplanar.
use parametric equations of a line :

$$x=a+ut$$
$$y=b+vt$$
$$z=c+wt$$
where $(a,b,c)$ is a point of the line, $(u,v,w)$ the vector director and $t$ a parameter.

Comment: Could you explain it in more detail

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071456/coplanar-lines-in-3d-plane/2071461#2071461

Comment: @koolman What i said is correct but downv.

Comment: I want to know about scalar product

Comment: @koolman The scalar product tells us about orthogonality of two vectors.